# Programmatically finding Chrome browser history

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am making a small Java application to show which URLs in Chrome that the user has visited the most. How would I access my browser history within Java?

Answer (score 8):

Create a `ContentObserver` class ...

```
static class ChromeOberver extends ContentObserver {   
    public ChromeOberver(Handler handler) { 
        super(handler);          
    } 

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) { 
        onChange(selfChange, null); 
    }    

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChange: " + selfChange);

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
              .query(CHROME_BOOKMARKS_URI, new String() {"title", "url"}, 
                                           "bookmark = 0", null, null);

        // process cursor results
    }
}
```

and register that class to monitor history/bookmark changes:

```
private static String CHROME_BOOKMARKS_URI = 
       "content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks";

ChromeOberver observer = new ChromeOberver();
resolver.registerContentObserver(CHROME_BOOKMARKS_URI, true, observer);
```

Don't forget the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

Comment: One thing missing: you need to query the URLs (was just searching a good sample ;)

Comment: Note that this is undocumented and unsupported.

Comment: @CommonsWare: that's true, though working quite well :) Do you have an "official" version?

Comment: @Trinimon: I am not aware that there is one.

Comment: I also want to get browser History in my app

Comment: @Dilip: above code is definitely working - however, as of Android M it is no longer allowed to read the browsers history (a `SecurityException` will be thrown; see https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser for details). You'll have to find another solution here. On former platforms it should still work, though you might have to use `content://com.android.chrome.browser/history` for newer Chrome versions.