# Android - get google search history?

Tags: android, search

You can easily get browsing history. But is there a way to get google search history word list? Of course I mean programmatically.

How can you do that?

Or do you simply need to parse browsing history and read that from urls?

Comment: https://history.google.com/history/ ?

Comment: I need my application installed on users cell phone to be able to get that data via API. You can't do that with that url. Especially that user has to give a password every time, and there are request limits as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332913/retrieve-old-searches-from-google-web-history

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically finding Chrome browser history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231715/programmatically-finding-chrome-browser-history)

Comment: It is not duplicate. I said in question, that I know how to get Chrome history!